# Get Value of specific Column while Login (C# Mysql)

Tags: c#, mysql, authentication, datareader, read-data

I am trying to make a login at the moment. I watched some videos and found a good way. Every user has an id, Username and Password. I want to get the id of the user who has just been logged in and save it in an Integer. I also tried it with an `ExecuteReader` but I get an Exception(*MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException*).

*My current Code is:*

```
 try
            {
                if (sqlCon.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
                {
                    sqlCon.Open();
                }
                string query = "SELECT COUNT(1) FROM Users_Table WHERE Username=@Username AND Password=@Password;";
                MySqlCommand sqlCmd = new MySqlCommand(query, sqlCon);
                sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", maintxtbox1.Text);
                sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", Hashed_Password);
                int count = Convert.ToInt32(sqlCmd.ExecuteScalar());
                if (count == 1)
                {
                    //Login correct
                }
                else
                {
                    //Login incorrect
                }
            }
            catch
            {
                //Exception
            }
            finally
            {
                sqlCon.Close();
            }
```

*The try with the ExecuteReader:*

```
try
            {
                if (sqlCon.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
                {
                    sqlCon.Open();
                }
                string query = "SELECT id,Username,Password FROM Users_Table WHERE Username=@Username AND Password=@Password;";
                MySqlCommand sqlCmd = new MySqlCommand(query, sqlCon);
                sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", maintxtbox1.Text);
                sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", Hashed_Password);

                MySqlDataReader datareader = sqlCmd.ExecuteReader();

                if (datareader.HasRows)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Test: " + datareader.GetString("id"));
                }
                else
                {
                    //Login incorrect
                }
            }
            catch
            {
                //Exception
            }
            finally
            {
                sqlCon.Close();
            }
```

I hope somebody can help me. Thank you in advance.

Comment: `string query = "SELECT COUNT(1) FROM Users_Table WHERE Username=@Username AND Password=@Password;";` Why are you counting the number of results from such query? Do you expect to get 1 as result in case there is a result that matches?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to my Question by myself. I forgot the `while(datareader.Read())` in the `ìf(datareader.HasRows)` query. Here is my working Code:

```
try
            {
                if (sqlCon.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
                {
                    sqlCon.Open();
                }
                string query = "SELECT * FROM Users_Table WHERE username=@Username AND password=@Password;";
                MySqlCommand sqlCmd = new MySqlCommand(query, sqlCon);
                sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", maintxtbox1.Text);
                sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", Hashed_Password);
                MySqlDataReader datareader = sqlCmd.ExecuteReader();
                if (datareader.HasRows)
                {
                    while (datareader.Read())
                    {
                        UserID = datareader.GetInt32("id");
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    //Incorrect Password
                }

            }
            catch
            {
                //Error
            }
            finally
            {
                sqlCon.Close();
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try and use the *Read* method:

```
if(datareader.Read()){
    MessageBox.Show("Test: "+datareader.GetString(0));
}
```

***EDIT:***
To make good use and disposal of resources I recommend using the MySqlDataReader inside a *using* block, e.j.

```
using(MySqlDataReader reader = new sqlCmd.ExecuteReader()){
    if(reader.Read()){
        MessageBox.Show("Test: "+reader.GetString(0));
    }
}
```

Comment: you can also use `while( reader.Read() ) ...` if you want to iterate through multiple results.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer. I tried it with a DataReader in the above code snippet, but it only got an exception I also tried it with `reader.GetString(0)` instead of `reader.GetString("id")`, but it won´t work. I can't use the while because I need the ID of the User that has just logged in and not every ID. Do you know how I can fix the Exception or do you have another Solution? Thanks in advance